# How to display input value as something else and still get the value?

Tags: php, html, css

I get pagination number from user input value like this:

```
$html .= "<input type='submit' name='next' value='$next_page_number' />";
```

I want to display this input value text as an arrow '→'.
How can I do this and still get the input value from `$_POST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hidden input to store the actual value, having the name you currently assigned to your submit button.

```
<input type='hidden' name='next' value='$next_page_number' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Your arrow thing' />
```

From the `$_POST` point of view, it does not know or care what kind of input the value originated in. It only knows what the input is named and the value it holds.

Comment: Or pass is in Query String... then you can bookmark and go straight to a specific page of results.

Comment: @Brian depends if the backend system is already engineered to read from `$_POST` rather than from `$_GET`.

Comment: Of course, just giving another idea :) - I did up-vote your answer... so not disagreeing!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about IE7 or lower, you can use:

```
<button type=\"submit\" name=\"next\" value=\"$next_page_number\"> → </button>
```

IE7 will send the button's `innerHTML`, that is, "`→`" and not the `value` attribute's content.